# Throwing an exception on the following method in java

Tags: java, exception, bluej

I need to Modify the removeDetails method (see below) so that it throws this exception if its key parameter is not a key that is in use.

```
public void removeDetails(String key)
    {
        if(key == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null key passed to removeDetails.");
        }
        if(keyInUse(key)) {
            ContactDetails details = book.get(key);
            book.remove(details.getName());
            book.remove(details.getPhone());
            numberOfEntries--;
        }

    }
```

Any ideas on what exception would be suitable would be gratefully received

Comment: if you're not creating application-specific exceptions, what's wrong with throwing IllegalArgumentException?  As you describe it, it's an invalid key, so what's wrong with that?

Comment: could you be more specific? and what you have tried so far

Comment: check [Collection.remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove-java.lang.Object-), your method semantic seems to be close - essentially NPE for null key, boolean result to indicate non-existing key

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the java doc for `IllegalArgumentException` which says "Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument." I think  `IllegalArgumentException` should be fine for your requirement. But if you want to be more specific you can always create a custom exception.